# max-width is not working in mozilla and IE

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

The image is scaling based on browser width only in chrome but it is not working in IE and Mozilla Firefox. 
thumb img is working in all the browsers but only .play img max-width is not working
Here is my 
HTML

```
<div class="contai">
        <div> <img src="1.png" style="max-width:100%" /></div>
       <div class="thumb">
         <img src="2.jpg" />
              <div class="play"> <img src="videoImagePlay.png" /></div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
    .contai{
    width:100%;
}
.thumb{
    border: 1px solid rgb(226, 226, 226);
   position:relative; float:left; width:38%
}
.thumb img{
    max-width:100%
}
.play{
     position:absolute; top:30%; left:35%
}
.play img{
    max-width:50%
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

play **class** `right : 0`

as like this

```
.play{     
     position:absolute; top:30%; left:35%; right:0;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/puS7u/

Answer (score 2):

see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BWQ2/1/). it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone in the future:
If the image has a parent which is a table (doesn't matter how high up in the node tree) then max-width will not work in FF or IE unless you have a specific pixel defined max width on the table. This does however work fine in Chrome.

The logic seems to be that FF and IE thinks that tables always should expand according to the content, disregarding max-width: 100%.

Not obvious which browser has the "correct" or best implementation.

Comment: Well, given that it understands width: 100%, I'd say it's clearly a box. Something with "width:X" should always be <= something with "max-width:X", or the names don't make any sense.